# Optional HTTP basic authentication in JMeter

Tags: authentication, jmeter, basic-authentication

I have a request, which can be used on an endpoint with and without authentication too, but response is different in these cases. I send request to path like `/MyService?wsdl`. I tried to use `HTTP Authorization Manager` added it to `HTTP Request` element with whole url to this service, but it isn't working. I am sure, that username and password are correct. How is it possible to debug authentication process?

Comment: Can you show your configuration and show the url that requires auth ? Thanks

Comment: I just provided url and username-password in manager. I use `JMeter 3.2`. Sorry, but service is internal.

Comment: Yes but at least show screenshots hiding what is confidential

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. HTTP Authorisation Manager respects JMeter's [Scoping Rules](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/UserManual/ScopingRules) so make sure it is located either on the same level as [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler or add it as a child of this sampler (in the latter case it will be applied to this sampler only)
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Base URL: protocol followed by IP address or hostname of the application under test
   - Username: your username
   - Password: your password
   - Mechanism: `BASIC_DIGEST`

     [image]
3. Assuming everything goes well you should see [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header added to your request

   [image: JMeter HTTP Authorisation Manager]

See [How to Use HTTP Basic Authentication in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter) article for more details.

---

Alternative solution is adding HTTP Header Manager and configuring it to send Authorisation header with the value of `${__base64Encode(username:password,)}`

[image: JMeter Header Manager for basic auth]

This approach assumes having [__Base64Encode](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Encodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) function installed, you can obtain it as a part of `Custom JMeter Functions` bundle using J[Meter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager - install custom functions]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) which is a Web Debugging Proxy to send requests from JMeter through it. You can configure [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) to use a proxy.

Make sure the **Authorization: Basic ...** header is sent within the request.

The [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) should be placed at the root of the thread group. You can then specify the full request path associated to each authorization.